# monaco editor: use "d.ts"-file from npm install for intellisense

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor, .d.ts

I need intellisense of an d.ts-file which I installed via `npm install mylibname`.

The monaco-component provides an function `addExtraLib` like this example:
[Microsoft Monaco Example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults)

What I don't understand is: All examples I found have to know the source-code to add it as the first parameter to `addExtraLib(myKnownSourceCode)`

But I just want to use the whole "d.ts"-file for intellisense.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpret the source parameter. This is just an arbitrary string and I'm not even sure it's used for anything visible outside of monaco-editor.

Instead just call `addExtraLib(typings, "myLibrary")` or similar.

Side note: this is a global setting for the monaco editor, which means you cannot have different typings in different editors. This is sometimes not what you want and you can use `setExtraLib` instead. This is however only a partial solution. As soon as you have different editors on the same page/in the same window, which require different typings, this will not work well.

The `typings` parameter is a simple string containing an ambient declaration of TS types. The [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.47.0#example-extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults) shows how this should look like:

```js
// extra libraries
var libSource = [
    "declare class Facts {",
    "    /**",
    "     * Returns the next fact",
    "     */",
    "    static next():string",
    "}",
].join("\n");
var libUri = "ts:filename/facts.d.ts";
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(libSource, libUri);
```

In fact, I recommend to check all the examples there out to learn how to use Monaco.

Comment: Could you expand this just a tiny bit to show the actual syntax that goes into `typings`? (is it a string, array, object, and if the latter two, what goes in it, etc)